# Pass an id and get it from actionLink to view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, html.actionlink

I have this ActionLink into view named catalog

```
@Html.ActionLink("Formations", "Index", "Formation", new { id = item.Id },null)
```

and I want to get the list of formations of this catalog id.

How can I do this ?

In my database I have two tables :

```
Catalog:idC (PK),NameC,Date
Formation:idF(PK),idC(FK),NameF.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view's name is Catalog, you need to change your ActionLink to point to the corresponding action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Formations", "Catalog", "Formation", new { id = item.Id }, null)
```

action:

```
public ActionResult Catalog(int id)
{
  var formations = db.Formations.Where(f => f.idC == id).ToList;

  return View(formations);
}
```

view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.Formation>
// loop your formations
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  // each formation iteration loops here
}
```